# How do I replace ActiveMQ Artemis with a standalone ActiveMQ "Classic" in Wildfly 10?

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic, wildfly, wildfly-10

I want to use a standalone ActiveMQ "Classic" instead of the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis on my Wildfly 10 server, but I can't get it to work. I've deployed the ActiveMQ resource adapter `activemq-rar-5.14.1.rar` and  in `standalone.xml` I've created a `resource-adapter`:

```xml
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0">
        <session-bean>
            <stateless>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </stateless>
            <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
            <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
        </session-bean>
        <mdb>
            <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="activemq"/>
            <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
        </mdb>
        ...

    <resource-adapter id="activemq">
    <archive>
        activemq-rar-5.14.1.rar
    </archive>
    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
    <config-property name="ServerUrl">
        tcp://localhost:61616
    </config-property>
    <config-property name="UserName">
        defaultUser
    </config-property>
    <config-property name="UseInboundSession">
        false
    </config-property>
    <config-property name="Password">
        defaultPassword
    </config-property>
    <connection-definitions>
        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">
            <xa-pool>
                <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>false</prefill>
                <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
            </xa-pool>
            <recovery>
                <recover-credential>
                    <user-name>defaultUser</user-name>
                    <password>defaultPassword</password>
                </recover-credential>
            </recovery>
        </connection-definition>
    </connection-definitions>
    <admin-objects>
        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/jms/queue/MyTestQueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MyTestQueue">
            <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                MyTestQueue
            </config-property>
        </admin-object>
        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/jms/queue/MySecondTestQueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MySecondTestQUeue">
            <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                MySecondTestQueue
            </config-property>
        </admin-object>                         
    </admin-objects>
    </resource-adapter>
```

I've also removed the subsystem `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">` and the extension `<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq"/>` from `standalone.xml`.

When I now try to deploy my application I get an error saying:

```
`No message listener of type javax.jms.MessageListener found in resource adapter activemq
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used artemis in this way yet but integrated artemis 1.5.3 with spring 4.x. Here are my artemis configuration:
Two nodes are communicating with udp broadcasting.

You can check the project out: https://github.com/mtorak/disttrans

Cheers